# How to loop inside a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop my function that way if you don't type the correct input it starts again from the beginning and you can try to input pounds, euros, or yen again

```
def moneyConversion():

    print("You can convert dollars to either pounds, euros, or yen")

    convert_to = input("What currency do you want to convert to? ")
    amount = int(input("How much would you like to convert? "))

    while True:
        if convert_to == "pounds":
            amount *= .65
        elif convert_to == "euros":
            amount *=  1.03
        elif convert_to == "yen":
            amount *= 145.73
        else:
            print("You must pick either pounds, euros, or yen") 

        print(amount)


    return convert_to 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your loop is wrong in the first place, since this is a `while True`, it'll keep repeating the code block, you have to exit the `while` with a `break`, or if you'd like to repeat the iteration, you can do `continue`.

Comment: There is no `main` function, so you must be getting `NameError` that `main` is not defined.

Comment: In case some of the solutions helped you, don't forget to add an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. You only need to loop until a correct currency is given. Once it's ok, you can break out of the loop and convert safely.

```py
def money_conversion():
    print("You can convert dollars to either pounds, euros, or yen")

    convert_to = None
    amount = int(input("How much would you like to convert? "))
    possible_conversions = ["pounds", "euros", "yen"]

    while convert_to not in possible_conversions:
        convert_to = input("What currency do you want to convert to? ")

    if convert_to == "pounds":
        amount *= .65
    elif convert_to == "euros":
        amount *=  1.03
    elif convert_to == "yen":
        amount *= 145.73

    print(amount)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    money_conversion()
```

*Edit: this code isn't completely safe, it just solves your problem. More verification should be added on the inputed amount for instance.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the input again and add `break` in loop when `convert_to` is working.

You can also add .lower() to your input that'll make that the input value will be in lowercase so you won't have issues if you input something like Euros.

Example:

```py
def moneyConversion():
    print("You can convert dollars to either pounds, euros, or yen")

    convert_to = input("What currency do you want to convert to? ").lower()
    amount = int(input("How much would you like to convert? "))

    while True:
        if convert_to == "pounds":
            amount *= .65
            break
        elif convert_to == "euros":
            amount *=  1.03
            break
        elif convert_to == "yen":
            amount *= 145.73
            break
        else:
            convert_to = input("You must pick either pounds, euros, or yen").lower()

        print(amount)


    return convert_to 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    money_conversion()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def moneyConversion():
    print("You can convert dollars to either pounds, euros, or yen")
    
    collected_input = False
    while not collected_input:
        convert_to = input("What currency do you want to convert to? ").lower()
        collected_input = convert_to in ['pounds', 'euros', 'yen']
        if not collected_input:
            print("currency must be pounds, euros, or yen")

    amount = int(input("How much would you like to convert? "))
    converted = {
        'pounds':lambda amt:amt*.65,
        'euros':lambda amt:amt*1.03,
        'yen':lambda amt:amt*145.73
    }[convert_to](amount)

    print(converted)
    return convert_to 

if __name__ == '__main__:
    moneyConversion()
```

Another graceful error-check you can do, is follow the same method for the amount input so that you don't get an error on a float input.

Comment: This avoids some of the pitfalls that can be hard to debug in a larger program with the while true: if elif: break paradigm. A clear test is set 'collected_input' that tells you what the test is right away, if the condition is not successful the loop tells you directly why. Additionally, the if:break statements are replaced with a dictionary that uses your input as a key to return the correct function,

Comment: Thank you! This helped clarify a lot. I'm super new to python

Comment: What does the lambda amt:amt do? As in, what is it used for in this situation

Comment: lambda in python declares an anonymous, single expression function. Its useful in this case because it allows you put off the evaluation of the amount conversion until the program knows which 'convert_to' to use. Using converted[convert_to] returns a lambda function that takes an input labelled 'amt' and returns the output of the function. So the syntax: converted[convert_to](amount) points to the function and then passes 'amount' to the function. Without the lambda function the expressions in the dictionary would all evaluate as the dictionary is constructed.

Comment: do = lambda x:x+5  would basically be the same as def do(x): return x+5

Comment: lambda amt: amt*.65 just declares a function that takes an input labelled 'amt' and multiplies it times .65 and returns the output

Answer (score 0):

```py
    def moneyConversion():
    
        # Take convert_to input
        print("You can convert dollars to either pounds, euros, or yen")
        convert_to = input("What currency do you want to convert to? ")
        
        # If "convert_to" input is either one of the available currencies, execute conversion codes
        if (convert_to == "pounds" or convert_to == "euros" or convert_to == "yen"):
            amount = int(input("How much would you like to convert? "))
        
            if convert_to == "pounds":
                amount *= .65
            elif convert_to == "euros":
                amount *=  1.03
            elif convert_to == "yen":
                amount *= 145.73
        
            print(amount)
            return convert_to
            
        # Else restart the function.
        else:
            moneyConversion()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        moneyConversion()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def moneyConversion():
    print("You can convert dollars to either pounds, euros, or yen")
    convert_to = input("What currency do you want to convert to? ")
    amount = int(input("How much would you like to convert? "))
    if convert_to in ["pounds","euros","yen"]:
        if convert_to == "pounds":
            amount *= .65
        elif convert_to == "euros":
            amount *=  1.03
        elif convert_to == "yen":
            amount *= 145.73
        print(amount)
        return convert_to
    else:
        print("You must pick either pounds, euros, or yen")
        return moneyConversion()
```

You can use recursion for the function to call itself. Please note that I added a validation step to test if the input was an allowed value. I would recommend using `convert_to.lower().strip()` to normalize the input and make it a bit more user friendly. Additionally, you could add the option to pass in an amount so that upon recursion the user is not required to redo that input.

```
def moneyConversion(amount: int=None) -> str:
    if amount == None:
        print("You can convert dollars to either pounds, euros, or yen")
        amount = int(input("How much would you like to convert? "))
    convert_to = input("What currency do you want to convert to? ")
    if convert_to in ["pounds","euros","yen"]:
        if convert_to == "pounds":
            amount *= .65
        elif convert_to == "euros":
            amount *=  1.03
        elif convert_to == "yen":
            amount *= 145.73
        print(amount)
        return convert_to
    else:
        print("You must pick either pounds, euros, or yen")
        return moneyConversion(amount)
```